# preserve breakpoints on refresh firefox

Tags: debugging, firefox, browser, breakpoints

I put a breakpoint using the debugger in firefox. On refresh, the breakpoints go away and the webpage loads completely. What may be the issue? I was able to successfully preserve breakpoint in chrome.

Comment: it preserved after I restarted firefox. strange behaviour. maybe happenes when debugging for the first time.